# Request cookie not sent in IE11 with AngularJS P3P WithCredentials

Tags: angularjs, cookies, internet-explorer-11, httpresponse, p3p

I'm writing a web app with Java back end on Tomcat, and AngularJS front end and all works fine in Chrome, Firefox, etc. but NOT IE 11.

The problem is that the initial login is returning a "Set-Cookie" but the cookie is NOT included in subsequent requests (using $http in Angular 2).

- I'm running a local tomcat server (so no clock/time difference issue)
- The login is returning both a "Set-Cookie" AND a P3P header
- Angular http service is set "withCredentials=true" as default
- There are no underscores in the domain name

Login Call:-

[image: Initial "login" call]

Subsequent API call:-

[image]

Anyone any ideas what I'm missing!?!?

Comment: Also now added the following config option but still not working...
-Dorg.apache.tomcat.util.http.ServerCookie.FWD_SLASH_IS_SEPARATOR=false